# React Native (android module in kotlin) " Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy. "

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build an React Native app (Android) after I upgraded kotlin from 1.4.32 to 1.6.0 to use jetpack compose

```
buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        compose true
    }
```

and now I got a strange error with a screaming warning:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon
Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/firestore' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v10.8.1 but found v10.4.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/messaging' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v10.8.1 but found v10.4.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
warning: flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies
warning: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:

-XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes

This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!

exception: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3399)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFChar(ObjectInputStream.java:3804)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3701)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:3497)
        at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.utils.PluginUtilsKt.decodePluginOptions(pluginUtils.kt:39)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.synthetic.AndroidCommandLineProcessor.processOption(AndroidComponentRegistrar.kt:91)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParserKt.processCompilerPluginsOptions(PluginCliParser.kt:125)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.processPluginOptions(PluginCliParser.kt:83)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.loadPlugins(PluginCliParser.kt:72)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.loadPluginsSafe(PluginCliParser.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.loadPlugins(CLICompiler.kt:179)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:69)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:76)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:227)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit$default(CLITool.kt:222)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:214)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:271)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

This is not easy to debug, and I never seen this before. Can anyone give me a hand on this one? Thanks!